# Calculating mechanical power of an electrical motor

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, power

*The total power of a powered drill is 850 watts (the rated value written on the drill's casing) and the current at the supply voltage of 230 volts is 3.7 amperes according to the formula $I = P/U$. Calculate the mechanical power.*

Now, we keep in mind that the drill produces mechanical AND heat energy. Thus the total power is the sum of mechanical power and heat power. Now my thinking is that we use the Joule-Lenz law $Q=I^2Rt$ to find heat power. I calculate the resistance to be approx 62,2 ohms with Ohms law. But my answer is a nonsensical 850 watts - the total power of the drill.

Comment: There isn't enough information here, the question as posed can't be answered. The power could just as well be that of a toaster which does no mechanical work.

Comment: @allyson bryce Your formula for heat power should be $Q=I^2R$, where $I=I(t)$ is some function of time and $R$ is the *impedance* since the circuits involved are AC.

Comment: By definition, P=IV, so you should get 851W; minus the 850W, you can get the rather unrealistic guesstimation that 1W is the heat output. I think your question is unanswerable as Puk identified.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I think the 1 W is just rounding error anyway.

Comment: @Puk yes, I am also of the same thinking. Which is why I said I agree with your assessment that the question is unanswerable as-is.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ill-posed question. First, some useful background:

A drill motor's *mechanical power rating* is its torque times its RPM at its *design point under load* and is expressed in *horsepower* where one horsepower is equivalent to 746 watts. The design point RPM is usually taken as *half the no-load RPM*.

The *electrical power rating* of a drill motor is its current flow times its source voltage when operating at its design point as defined above. Note that in a drill motor, its torque output is proportional to its current flow and its RPM is proportional to the source voltage.

If the motor is *lossless* (100% efficient) then (torque x RPM) = (voltage x current) meaning that a motor rated at 746 watts (electrical) would produce one horsepower (mechanical). In your example, a lossless 850 watt motor would be producing about 1.14 horsepower.

So... the correct answer to this ill-posed question is 1.14 horsepower *assuming a 100% efficient motor*.  Anything more accurate than this requires that we know what the actual *motor DC resistance at the operating point* is (which will *not* be 62 ohms!) so we can calculate the ohmic losses of the wire in the motor, deduct it from the nameplate rating, and convert the reduced power to horsepower.

P.S. in an actual drill motor operating at its rated voltage but *running free without a load*,  the power output is *zero* (no load, by definition) and its current flow is nearly zero as well (because its *back EMF* is almost equal and opposite to its *source voltage*, meaning almost no current flow- and so no ohmic losses.

we say "almost" in this case because even at the no-load condition, the motor bearings are dissipating a little power and the rotating armature is stirring up the air inside the motor, which dissipates a little power too.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake: You calculated your resistor with U/I. So you assume there is an resistor that eats all the current of the drill. Certainly then its power is U*I and then clearly your calculation ends up showing that all the power is consumed by the resistor, which was your initial assumption in the first place.

Your drill also will not draw all the power when it is running idle. When you use your drill the efficiency of electric motors is typically around 60 to 70%. But you can not tell this just from the power ratings at all.

When the motor is idle the coils on the magnets of the motor will draw a current but this one is like the one on an inductor 90 degrees out of phase with the voltage and thus consumes no real power. Power is just used to build up a magnetic field in half of the phase and then change it to an opposite field in the next half. So the power is constantly oscilating between mains and your drill. This current also causes some ohmic resistance in the imperfect  and thus some loss of power.

Once you use your drill the energy that is in the magnetic field is actually used to force the magnet to turn against the resistance of the screw. So the energy is no longer oscillating back and force between the drill and mains but now moving into the drillbit.